# How to do for loop on template (not range) in Go?

Tags: go, go-templates

Simple, i need for loop in golang on view(template). I can not seams to find on how to do that. Or how to do same thing with `range`?

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}

for i := 1; i <= len(a); i++ {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

how to do this on view?

Comment: What is a "view"?

Comment: @JimB it is template not view sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. `range` is the only way to form a loop in Go templates. You can feed it the output of a function that produces a for loop for you. The [`until`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig) function from the sprig library does something like this. It would be trivial to create your own, as well.

Comment: ok thanks for this